# Netbeans Maven Window

Tags: maven, netbeans, netbeans-8

I've got a hopefully simple question.

How can I show the Maven Goals in a Netbeans 8 window all the time, instead of only in the Navigator window?

It's so useful, I just want it docked all the time.

[image]

-- Shane

Answer (score 1):

you cannot currently. It's part of navigator windows, sensitive to Maven project selection now. You might want to file an enhancement request at netbeans.org.

Comment: Bummer, ok thanks for answering. I'll submit an enhancement request.